# Reserved space for closed questions

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions

Maybe this should go to meta.stackexchange, but it seems that every site has its policy, so I'll start from here.

I've seen that closed questions remain visible in the home and also in the other tabs. So, why don't create a section to group all closed questions and remove them from other tabs?

Maybe I've misunderstood the meaning of closed question?

Comment: They will disappear, I believe, when they have two downvotes. I will have to get a reference.

Comment: @Kortuk Now I know that they don't disappear, as there are two in the main page :)

Comment: @clabacchio there may be a difference as to what is consider the "main page" If you are at "http://electronics.stackexchange.com " then you *wont* see the closed questions with 2 down votes, but if you are at "http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions " you *will* see every question.

Answer (score 2):

The humans who edit, close, and vote on questions aren't perfect: They're humans!  For this reason, all edits and closures cause questions to be bumped to the top of the 'active' list.  This bumping allows actions to be audited.  Closing a question isn't permanent.  The same number of votes can reopen a closed question.  If no one saw these questions, they would be much less likely to be reversed.

After a few downvotes accumulate, a question will be removed from the front page.  We don't push it off immediately in case the first downvoters made a mistake.  After several downvotes, though, it's almost certainly a poor question and we don't want it on the fron page.

Also note that *closed* questions with downvotes (and no upvoted answers, if I remember correctly) are deleted automatically after a period of time, so they won't pollute the archive or Google results.

Comment: Ok I agree, but I was just suggesting to create a page similar to "review" that would allow who is interested in closed questions to check them; in fact, removing seems too much also for me, but I would like to filter them after some time...maybe a checkbox could work?

Comment: Ah, I see.  You can get that by searching for `closed:1` in the search box: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3A1.  There are lots of [other options for searching](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=).

Comment: Oh, nice tool this Advanced Super Ninja research! :)

Comment: @clabacchio, kevinVermeer is a ninja with quite a few SE tools.